# Does the MongoDb Node JS package work with cron and crontab?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cron

I'm trying to get my Node.js script that populates a MongoDB database daily to run using crontab. Without crontab, my Node.js script does what it should be, which is connecting to the Mongo DB and populating it.

But with crontab it stops at the require('mongodb') statement with no error being printed on stdout!

I should also mention my other 3rd party modules are being imported properly (Like Axios for example), just failing at MongoDB's import. And that only when I run using crontab cron jobs!

Is the Node JS MongoDB package not compatible with crontab?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've specified - it's a script I wrote in Node.js that normally runs without running it as a cron job properly, but doesn't run in cron job (using crontab) and fails when I try to import the MongoDB package! \I should also mention my other 3rd party modules are being imported properly (Like Axios for example)

Comment: Removed the bash tag. You are right. Also, the code is proprietary, hence I'm not going to be able to post it. However, the point of failure is in the import statements - so I wouldn't attribute it to the code...if I remove that import statements, my code continues! I do appreciate the feedback though!